# Webpack Define plugin replacement is evaluated but not injected

Tags: javascript, webpack, phaser-framework

I have JS library foo which is being built with webpack which includes and builds the source code of the Phaser 3 library. Phaser 3 uses the define plugin to exclude parts of itself, for example replacing "typeof CANVAS_RENDERER" with false.

The issue I'm running into is this. when i include this block in my webpack config

```
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "typeof CANVAS_RENDERER": JSON.stringify(false),
    }),
```

the kind of output i get is this

```
if (typeof WEBGL_RENDERER && typeof CANVAS_RENDERER)
{}

if (typeof WEBGL_RENDERER && !typeof CANVAS_RENDERER)
{
    WebGLRenderer = __webpack_require__(/*! ../renderer/webgl/WebGLRenderer */ "../node_modules/phaser/src/renderer/webgl/WebGLRenderer.js");

    //  Force the type to WebGL, regardless what was requested
    config.renderType = CONST.WEBGL;

    game.renderer = new WebGLRenderer(game);
}
```

Where `typeof CANVAS_RENDERER` has obviously been evalutated to false and as a result the function body has been optmised out but it didnt replace the original statement causing the code to go down the empty path when its run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, if the plugin can't ***resolve*** each part of the `if` clause, in your case `typeof WEBGL_RENDERER`(since this is not defined in the `new webpack.DefinePlugin`), it doesn't resolve the rest.

With other words, if you define both in the plugin it should work:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "typeof CANVAS_RENDERER": JSON.stringify(false),
    "typeof WEBGL_RENDERER": JSON.stringify(true),
}),
```

Atleast that solved the described problem, in my test setup.

Comment: yep, that fixed it, i dont know why i didnt thy that myself but thank you. still odd behaviour from the plugin in my option.

Comment: @kits, true absolutely strange, and sadly I could find any information about this in the documentation, to confirm this with _"hard data"_.